# Sum product from the cell that contain IF AND

Tags: excel-formula

How to sum value from the column that have IF AND function?

[How to find sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhVd6.png)

I try to sum the value but it return 0.

Comment: Not enough detail here. What formula did you use to try to sun that column? A simple SUM should work.

Comment: Your values are stored as text

Comment: @lurker 

this is the formula that I used:

=IF(AND(A1="A",B1="Sugar"),"30", IF(AND(A1="B",B1="Sugar"),"150", IF(AND(A1="C",B1="Sugar"),"250", 
IF(AND(A1="A",B1="Salt"),"80", IF(AND(A1="B",B1="Salt"),"40", IF(AND(A1="C",B1="Salt"),"100"," " ))))))

The value will return based on the condition IF AND. I wish to find sum. I use simple sum formula but it return 0.

Comment: @ScottCraner how to stored the value is Number?

Comment: Remove the "" around the numbers in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Instead of using `=SUM()` use `=SUM(VALUE())` instread, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (instead of only <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

Comment: If the source cells are all numbers entered as text, you can also just select the cells and tell Excel to convert them to numbers.